# forbidden showing when grabbing data

Tags: php

I wanna grab data from a websites. But it is showing me forbidden. 
look at this code :

```
<?php
$link='http://www.sitedossier.com/site/wikipedia.org';
$so=file_get_contents($link);
echo ($link);
echo "</br>";
echo ($so);
?>
```

But it is showing forbidden. Script result is :

```
http://www.sitedossier.com/site/wikipedia.org
Forbidden.
```

But if i give only main site name : `http://www.sitedossier.com` for grabbing data. It's grabbing.

What is the problem here ? My Script is wrong or site is forbidden for any script ? 
If that, then how can i bypass it ?

Thanks

Comment: They are blocking bots. Respect it.

Comment: So, i need to collect data manually ? it's hard.

Comment: @slash-bang: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0tdsL4kvp_I

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some sites don't like bots.
You can work-around this using cURL if you have it:

```
<?php
$ch = curl_init('http://www.sitedossier.com/site/wikipedia.org');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:20.0) Gecko/20121221 Firefox/20.0');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, 'http://www.sitedossier.com');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, 'cookie.txt');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, 'cookie.txt');

$data = curl_exec($ch);
echo $data;
?>
```

EDIT:
It works now. I guess they set a cookie that the site requires.

Comment: I Used `CURL` , but same result .

Comment: Oh neat, that doesn't work either. Gimme a second, I'll figure out why it doesn't work.

Comment: Ok,and check with main site. it's grabbing data from main site. But can't from folder.

Comment: It works now slash-bang :) Sorry 'bout that.

Answer (score 0):

That website requires a User-Agent string, which `file_get_contents` does not send.

Use `fsockopen` and related functions to ensure the correct headers are sent.

Comment: well, can't he use `cURL` for this purpose?

Comment: I used `CURL` function with user-agent . but same result.